# Rest Framework Tutorial IntegrityError creating snippets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working my way through the Django Rest Framework tutorial and I am stuck on Part 4.

After adding permissions to the views, it says to create a couple of snippets. I logged in through the browsable API and tried to post a snippet like this:

```
{
"title": "snippet",
"code": "print 123"
}
```

When I do I get:

IntegrityError at /snippets/

NOT NULL constraint failed: snippets_snippet.owner_id

Anyone know what's going on here?

```
Traceback:
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  403.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  400.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/grez/web/resttutorial/snippets/views.py" in post
  23.             serializer.save()
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  599.             self.save_object(self.object, **kwargs)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save_object
  1041.         obj.save(**kwargs)
File "/home/grez/web/resttutorial/snippets/models.py" in save
  36.         super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  591.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  619.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  700.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  733.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  920.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  549.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/grez/restenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  485.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /snippets/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: snippets_snippet.owner_id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was running through this tutorial tonight and hit the same error. It seems the tutorial is a version or so behind the actual framework maybe? Regardless, I was able to get snippets to save after a bit of research.

Where the tutorial says to do this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

I switched to this:

```
def pre_save(self, snip):
    snip.owner = self.request.user
```

It seems that that `perform_create` method no longer exists or is called, so the `owner` never gets set, thus the error we saw. I'm not sure if what I did is the *correct* way of solving the problem, but it seems to work!

Here's a link to the docs where I figured the above out: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview

Comment: Thanks very much! I was convinced that the perform_create() must not be correct, but I was unsure how to check or what method to use instead. Great answer!

Comment: Right. First time having a question answered. :)

Comment: I think pre_save is the old method: "Note: These methods replace the old-style version 2.x pre_save, post_save, pre_delete and post_delete methods, which are no longer available." http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Comment: What classes are you using to implement the view? perform_create is called by by the [CreateModelMixin.create method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin) as the documentation says, so you have to inherit your view from that mixin. E.g. ModelViewSet automatically uses it, but GenericApiView does not.

Answer (score 10):

It seems that the answer depends on the Django REST framework version. Answer below has been tested on versions 3.2.4 and 3.10.3. If you are using these versions and class based views, you should put:

```
serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

instead of

```
serializer.save()
```

in SnippetList.post() method, so that it looks as follows:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The function pre_create() should be excluded from the SnippetList class.

Answer (score 2):

you can update the save() parameters in the post method for the SnippedList:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

perform_create is in the CreateModelMixin, your view should be a subclass of generics.ListCreateAPIView

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I figured out that I add a `perform_create` method to `SnippetSerializer` but it need to be added in `SnippetList` view, it is described in tutorial.